# Find $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x+1)^2(2x-4)^3}{(2x-1)^4}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x+1)^2(2x-4)^3}{(2x-1)^4}$$

I want to divide by $x^4$, but wouldn't I need to multiply out the whole thing and make a mess?

Is there a more simple way of doing this?

Comment: You don't need to multiply out, you can divide each parenthesis by the appropriate power of $x$.

Comment: But surely, I'd need to multiply out to do that?

Comment: No, you don't. By the way, your new version has degree five in the numerator and four in the denominator, so it doesn't have a finite limit. $$\frac{x(1+1/x)^2(2-4/x)^3}{(2-1/x)^4}$$

Comment: On the solution sheet, the answer is infinity, so that makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that your function has degree five in the numerator, degree four in the denominator, so the limit will be $\pm \infty$ as $x\to \infty$. So there really is no need to divide numerator and denominator by $x^4$, and certainly no need to expand the factors.

Comment: Ah, okay thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Note that, generally speaking, such a limit of a ratio of polynomials is always the limit of the ratio of the leading terms since they dominate as $x\rightarrow\infty$. You can write down the leading terms by inspection to see this is $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{8x^5}{16x^4} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} x/2 = +\infty$

Comment: The moment I thought  posting my answer I saw that you already post your answer with the same idea. Nice and quick answer;-)+1

Comment: @amWhy: Nice approach +1